# mypy: class with custom __add__ method gives [operator] error 'Unsupported operand types for + ("MyCustomClass" and "Callable[..., Any]")'

Tags: python, mypy

I have a custom class similar to:

```
class DailyAmounts:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.daily_map: Dict[date, int] = dict()
    self.total: int = 0

  def __daily_math(self: 'DailyAmounts', other: 'DailyAmounts', function: Callable[[int, int], int]) -> 'DailyAmounts':
    if not isinstance(other, DailyAmounts):
      raise ValueError("Only {} can be added".format(DailyAmounts.__name__))

    res = DailyAmounts()
    days = list(set(self.daily_map.keys()) | set(other.daily_map.keys()))
    for day in days:
      amount = function(self.daily_map.get(day, 0), other.daily_map.get(day, 0))
      res[day] = amount

    return res
    
  def __add__(self: 'DailyAmounts', other: 'DailyAmounts') -> 'DailyAmounts':
    def function(a: int, b: int) -> int:
      return a + b

    addition: DailyAmounts = self.__daily_math(other, function)
    return addition

  def __sub__(self: 'DailyAmounts', other: 'DailyAmounts') -> 'DailyAmounts':
    def function(a: int, b: int) -> int:
      return a - b

    subtraction: DailyAmounts = self.__daily_math(other, function)
    return subtraction

   def __iter__(self: 'DailyAmounts') -> Iterator[date]: 
     return iter(self.daily_map)
```

Another class has a `DailyAmounts` as an attribute:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.daily_amounts: DailyAmounts = DailyAmounts() # values calculated later elsewhere
```

This error and similar errors happen in multiple areas in the code base, but a simple example of the `[operator]` error is:

```
def some_function(old_item: Item):
  new_item = Item()
  # line below: Unsupported operand types for + ("DailyAmounts" and "Callable[..., Any]")  [operator]
  new_item.daily_amounts = old_item.daily_amounts + DailyAmounts() # basically make a copy
```

similar issue with mypy error `[index]`

```
def another_function():
  ...
  # line below: Unsupported target for indexed assignment ("Callable[..., Any]")  [index]
  for entry in my_item.daily_amounts.items():
    my_other_item.daily_amounts[entry[0]] = entry[1]
```

Comment: Just out of interest: why do you annotate `self` in these methods?

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike in my attempt to get the typing right for this class, I found an example here on SO doing that, so I attempted in case it would help. Will probably remove in the final code

Comment: You probably failed to paste your code to make a reproducible example. Best of my guess can be found in [this playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=d5afc29393f36fd04cfcf9b2e3107894) and does not show any of errors you report (but shows real errors, of course - your code won't work at runtime either).

Comment: No, this code is an oversimplification unfortunately, the real Item is a complex sqlalchemy model with many attributes, and I cut out a lot of methods from DailyAmounts as well.
Here's [a running playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=d5afc29393f36fd04cfcf9b2e3107894) which reproduces similar but not the same errors. Looks like I would have to make the sqlalchemy models like it is in my repo to get these same errors. I was hoping it might be obvious to any mypy expert! Thank you anyway.